# Why This Css Class Condition not work in react js?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, styles, conditional-statements

I am trying to use CSS conditions in class react but its not working i don't know i applied 4 conditions but not working i don't know where is wrong.

Thanks

```
<td className="lom">
                  <span
                    className={
                      (`${c.overall_score <= 4 ? "summary" : ""}`,
                      `${c.overall_score <= 6 ? "orange" : ""}`,
                      `${c.overall_score <= 8 ? "speed" : ""}`,
                      `${c.overall_score <= 10 ? "dynamic" : ""}`)
                    }
                  >
                    {c.overall_score}
                  </span>
                </td>
```

Comment: Use [classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) for multiple styles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using ternary condition sample application**

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    let arr = [
      { overall_score: 4 },
      { overall_score: 6 },
      { overall_score: 8 },
      { overall_score: 10 }
    ];

    return (
      <div>
        {arr.map(c => (
          <h3
            className={`${
              c.overall_score <= 4
                ? "summary"
                : c.overall_score <= 6
                ? "orange"
                : c.overall_score <= 8
                ? "speed"
                : c.overall_score <= 10
                ? "dynamic"
                : ""
            }`}
          >
            I'm colored
          </h3>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is syntax error. Try this one:

```
className={`${c.overall_score <= 4 ? "summary" : ""} 
  ${c.overall_score <= 6 ? "orange" : ""} 
  ${c.overall_score <= 8 ? "speed" : ""}
  ${c.overall_score <= 10 ? "dynamic" : ""}`
}
```

Or use [classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) like FortyTwo mention in comments. I suppose it will be better approach for you case.